# Диаграмма в Андроид

Tags: android

Есть ли какие-то средства у Андроида для построение диаграмм? Может библиотеки с подробным описанием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот наверное самая популярная библиотека [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)